# How to replace "35yrs" with "35 yrs" using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, textmate

I have a list that looks like this:

```
35yrs
74 yrs
40yrs
24yrs
36 yrs
```

I want to use regular expressions (in Textmate) to make the list look like this:

```
35 yrs
74 yrs
40 yrs
24 yrs
36 yrs
```

I have the search correct:

```regex
\d+[y][r][s]
```

What should the replace look like?

Comment: I don't know the program, but following your search information, would the replace be nearly the same but with a [ ] following the + sign? Blank space between brackets.

Comment: I'm using textmate which says you should use numbers (e.g., $1) in the replace field. I just don't know what to put as those numbers.

Comment: Try to put search as `(\d+)(yrs)`, and replace string as `$1 $2`

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Textmate supports advanced regular expression. Then you can use the following:

- Find: `(?<=\d)(?=yrs)`
- Replace:   <-- a space

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\d)    # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a digit before the current position
(?=yrs)    # positive lookahead, make sure we have literally "yrs" after the current position
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use capture groups.
Here's the regular expression to use:

```
(\d+)(yrs)
```

and in the replace field put this

```
\1 \2
```

> \1 represents the first group in () and \2 represents the second ()

Comment: This looks like it should work (the regex looks correct), but doesn't - at least as of *TextMate version 2.0.23*. It replaces the items without spaces between the digits and the yrs with "\1 \2". Weirdness. (The first two lines come out like `\1 \2` and `74 yrs`, for example.)